# How can i define arrays as 2D pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define SIZE 100

using namespace std;

int num, number = 1, a, b, x, y, startValue = 0, points = 0, chartSize, openCards = 0;

char* ptr1 = new char[SIZE*SIZE];
char* ptr2 = new char[SIZE * SIZE];
int* ptr3 = new int[SIZE * SIZE];

char rl, chart[SIZE][SIZE], letters[SIZE][SIZE], (*ptr1)[SIZE][SIZE] = &chart, (*ptr2)[SIZE][SIZE] = &letters;


void dynamicChart() {

    srand(time(NULL));
    cout << "Please enter the size of the chart(2,4,6,etc.):" << endl;
    cin >> chartSize;

    while (chartSize % 2 != 0 || chartSize <= 0) {
        cout << "Invalid chart size.Please enter another value.\n";
        cin >> chartSize;

    }
    int spaces = chartSize * chartSize, assigned[SIZE][SIZE] = { 0 },(*ptr3)[SIZE][SIZE] = &assigned;
    

    while (spaces != 0) {
        rl = 'A' + rand() % 26;
        int count = 0;
        while (count < 2) {
            int r1 = rand() % chartSize;
            int r2 = rand() % chartSize;
            if (!(*(*(*ptr3 + r1) + r2))) {
                *(*(*ptr2 + r1) + r2) = rl;
                *(*(*ptr3 + r1) + r2) = 1;
                count++;
            }
        }
        spaces -= 2;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < chartSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < chartSize; j++) {
            *(*(*ptr1 + i) + j) = '*';
        }
    }
}

void drawChart() {

    cout << "\n\n\n\n";
    cout << "     ";

    for (int i = 1; i < chartSize + 1; i++) {
        cout << i;
        cout << "\t    ";
    }

    cout << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < chartSize; i++) {
        cout << number;
        number++;
        for (int j = 0; j < chartSize; j++) {
            cout << "|";us
            cout << "   " <<  *(*(*ptr1 + i) + j);
            cout << "\t";

        }
        cout << endl;
    }



    number = 1;
}
void mainMenu() {

    cout << "Play(1)\tQuit(0)" << endl;
    cin >> num;
    while (num != 0 && num != 1) {
        cout << "Please enter a valid input." << endl;
        cin >> num;
    }
    if (num) {
        startValue = 1;
    }

}
void playGame1() {


    bool validInput = false;

    while (!validInput) {
        cout << "Points: " << points << endl;
        cout << "Enter a coordinate:\t\tQuit(0)" << endl;
        cin >> x;
        if (x == 0) {
            cout << "Quitting...";
            Sleep(1000);
            system("CLS");
            exit(1);
        }
        cin >> y;
        if (y == 0) {
            cout << "Quitting...";
            Sleep(1000);
            system("CLS");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (x > chartSize || y > chartSize || x <= 0 || y <= 0) {
            cout << "Invalid coordinates. Please try again.\n";
        }
        else {
            x--;
            y--;
            if (*(*(*ptr1 + x) + y) == '*') {
                *(*(*ptr1 + x) + y) = *(*(*ptr2 + x) + y);
            }
            else {
                cout << "This coordinate is occupied.Please enter another coordinate.\n";
                playGame1();
            }
            validInput = true;
        }
    }
}
void playGame2() {


    bool validInput = false;

    while (!validInput) {
        cout << "Points: " << points << endl;
        cout << "Enter a coordinate:\t\tQuit(0)" << endl;
        cin >> a;
        if (a == 0) {
            cout << "Quitting...";
            Sleep(1000);
            system("CLS");
            exit(1);
        }
        cin >> b;
        if (b == 0) {
            cout << "Quitting...";
            Sleep(1000);
            system("CLS");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (a > chartSize || b > chartSize || a <= 0 || b <= 0) {
            cout << "Invalid coordinates. Please try again.\n";
        }
        else {
            a--;
            b--;
            if (*(*(*ptr1 + a) + b) == '*') {
                *(*(*ptr1 + a) + b) = *(*(*ptr2 + a) + b);
            }
            else {
                cout << "This coordinate is occupied.Please enter another coordinate.\n";
                playGame2();
            }
            validInput = true;
        }
    }
}
void control() {

    if (*(*(*ptr1 + a) + b) == chart[x][y]) {
        openCards += 2;
        Sleep(1000);
        points += 3;
        system("CLS");
    }
    else {
        points -= 1;
        Sleep(1000);
        *(*(*ptr1 + a) + b) = chart[x][y] = '*';
        system("CLS");

    }
}

int main() {

    mainMenu();
    system("CLS");

    if (startValue) {
        dynamicChart();
        system("CLS");

        while (1) {

            drawChart();

            playGame1();
            system("CLS");
            drawChart();


            playGame2();
            system("CLS");
            drawChart();


            control();

            if (openCards == chartSize * chartSize) {
                drawChart();
                cout << "You won! With " << points << " points.";
                Sleep(3000);
                system("CLS");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "You have quitted.";
    }

    

    return 0;
}
```

This is a memory game that i am working on. I need to change the arrays to pointers and use dynamic memory allocation but i am not beeing able to do it. I am having error message  "operand of '*' must be a pointer but has type 'int'." whenever i try to use my pointers.

I tried to use pointer to pointer but it didn't worked out.Instead i had many more errors.

Comment: The answer to "how do I do this" is "you don't do that". You use `std::vector`, instead.

Comment: Pointer to pointer is the way to do this. Here's a suggestion, **practise** this on a small program, when you have understood how to do it on a small program go back to this program and try again.

Comment: Also all this `*(*(*ptr3 + r1) + r2) = 1;` is impossible to understand and completely unnecessary. You access a 2D array implemented with pointers in **exactly the same way** as a regular 2D array, i.e. `ptr3[r1][r2] = 1;` The rule is that `*(ptr + i)` means exactly the same thing as `ptr[i]`.

Comment: `*(*(*ptr1 + a) + b)` **looks horrible.** Don't write code like this.

Comment: Short answer: **Don't**. Old-school C practice is not recommended for modern C++. For the most part, you don't need to use raw pointers in C++ code. 2D arrays can have a multitude of implementations, depending on API demands: Large vs small, static vs dynamic dimensions, sparse vs crowded. None of them need explicit use of raw pointers.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here's a quick sample to get you started

```
// allocate 2D array
char** ptr1 = new char*[chartSize];
for (int i = 0; i < chartSize; i++) {
    ptr1[i] = new char[chartSize];

// initialise 2D array elements
for (int i = 0; i < chartSize; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < chartSize; j++) {
        ptr1[i][j] = '*';
    }
}
```

Once you have the arrays allocated everything else is (almost) exactly the same as regular arrays.

Comment: I don't believe that's an actually recommendable way how to do that in c++. That code leaks memory like a siehe.

Comment: I understood that i don't know much about pointers. I am going to study some pointers and going to fix my code after that. Thank you for your answers.